# How to develop Hybrid Mobile App by using Phonegap in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app

how can we develop Hybrid mobile app by using Phonegap in salesforce 
I have to scan the text and i have to insert the record in object

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use image option in file like below :

but if mobile browser doesnot support it use phonegap